# How to set routes on a linux EC2

Tags: linux, networking, ip, route

How do I set the below values in linux?

I'm able to set destination and gateway, but I can't find anything in the docs RE passing a flag for genmask, flags, metric, ref, use or Iface.

Can anyone provide the value to pass? I've been able to construct the below

```
sudo route add -net 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.96.0 tun0
```

But I need the full command to add the below;

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.96.0    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows a blatant lack of effort and research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
route add -net 10.0.0.0/24 gw 10.16.101.1 metric 100 dev ens192
```

Usage:

```
 inet_route [-vF] add {-host|-net} Target[/prefix] [gw Gw] [metric M] [mss Mss] [window W] [irtt I][mod] [dyn] [reinstate] [[dev] If]
```

About Flags:

> If the ‘metric’ is non zero then ‘G’ flag is set else not.

Also, you can use `ip r` command.